# How do you use an F-Curve with negative values?

Tags: fcurves

I want to use the start to finish values of

-1.7 -var = (driver value = 0) to -2.7 -var = (driver value = 1)

I've always done it in the expression as a math formula but I never learned to use the F-Curve to achieve the same results and once in a tutorial they make an example here:

https://youtu.be/1WmFaBlDBHs?t=118

But when I tried this with negative values I could only manage to turn the F-Curve into a mess.

How do you use negative values with F-Curves.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want the driven property to range from a value of 0 to 1, as the driving property ranges from a value of -2.7 to -1.7?

[image]

What we're saying is, we want a *function* [f(x)=y] where f(-2.7)=0 and f(-1.7)=1.  F-curves are *function* curves.  The X and Y are what we want to see on our graph-- points with those X,Y coordinates.

If you look on the sidebar, you can see that the control point I have selected has some fields for manual entry.  For this particular control point, it has a value of 0, at a keyframe of -1.7.  The other one, naturally, has a value of 1 at a keyframe of -2.7.

You can select a control and manually enter these numbers if you'd like.  That's what I did.

If editing these manually ever screws up your handles, and you want it back to being a *linear* function like I have here, you can select all your controls in the graph editor and use set handle keyframe type ('v' for me) -> vector, which points the handles at the adjacent controls.

Note that in 2.91.0, when you edit a control point to cross another control point (in the x axis), the fcurve re-orders the points, and you lose active selection of the control.  It's fine, you just need to reselect.